# Good Vs. Evil - Battle For Middle Earth - CodeWars

Tags: javascript

This is the code that I'm submitting for the "Good vs Evil" Kata on CodeWars:

https://www.codewars.com/kata/good-vs-evil/train/javascript

```
function goodVsEvil(good, evil) {
  good = good.split(' ');
  evil = evil.split(' ');

  //hobbits, men, elves, etc
  let goodWorth = [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 10];
  //orcs, men, wargs, etc  
  let evilWorth = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 5, 10];

  let goodArmyPoints = [];
  //multiply goodWorth by type:
  for (let i = 0; i < goodWorth.length; i++) {
    goodArmyPoints.push(good[i] * goodWorth[i]);
  }

  goodArmyPoints = goodArmyPoints.reduce(function (sum, value) {
    return sum + value;
  });

  let evilArmyPoints = [];
  for (let j = 0; j < evilWorth.length; j++) {
    evilArmyPoints.push(evil[j] * evilWorth[j]);
  }

  evilArmyPoints = evilArmyPoints.reduce(function (sum, value) {
    return sum + value;
  });

  if (evilArmyPoints < goodArmyPoints) {
    return "Battle Result: Good triumphs over Evil";
  } else if (evilArmyPoints > goodArmyPoints) {
    return "Battle Result: Evil eradicates all trace of Good";
  } else {
    return "Battle Result: No victor on this battle field";
  }

}
```

But I'm not sure what:

```
goodArmyPoints = goodArmyPoints.reduce(function (sum, value) {
    return sum + value;
  });
```

is doing exactly.

I see that [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) "executes a reducer function (which I've provided?) on each member of the array, resulting in a single output value".

But can someone please walk me through what `.reduce(function (sum, value)` is doing, exactly? Where is this function coming from? What are `sum` and `value`?

I'm still learning JavaScript and this is new to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I see at least two things about your code that could be improved.

```
  let goodArmyPoints = [];
  //multiply goodWorth by type:
  for (let i = 0; i < goodWorth.length; i++) {
    goodArmyPoints.push(good[i] * goodWorth[i]);
  }

  goodArmyPoints = goodArmyPoints.reduce(function (sum, value) {
    return sum + value;
  });
```

Here you allocate a whole *array* to store the results of multiplications, and then reduce over it. This extra array is wasteful. It would be much clearer and cleaner (and faster) to write simply

```
  let goodArmyPoints = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < goodWorth.length; ++i) {
    goodArmyPoints += good[i] * goodWorth[i];
  }
```

---

Another confusing thing about your original code is that in the line

```
  goodArmyPoints = goodArmyPoints.reduce(...);
```

you are *assigning over* `goodArmyPoints`. And not just assigning over its *value*, but actually changing its *type* — from "array of numbers" to "just a single number."

Since a variable's name usually reflects what's stored in it, and what's stored in it is usually a function of its *type*, it follows that variables of different types rarely end up with the same name. For example, if I had two variables, one that stored an array of point-values and one that stored a single point-value, I would probably name them `goodScores` and `goodScore`, or `goodPartialScores` and `goodTotal`, or something like that. But I definitely would not give them the *same exact* name!

By giving each variable a unique name, and never changing the type of an existing variable, we increase the understandability of the code. Because now, when the reader asks, "What is the type of variable `goodArmyPoints`?", we can actually give an answer! In your original code, if the reader asks "What is the type of variable `goodArmyPoints`?", all we can do is hedge: "Well, at this point in the code it's an array, but when we use it two lines later, it's a number..." That's a more complicated and confusing answer, which is just another way of saying that your original code is more complicated and confusing than the simplified code above.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this example

```
var numbers = [65, 44, 12, 4];

function getSum(total, num) {
  return total + num;
}

function myFunction(item) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = numbers.reduce(getSum);
}
```

Given a function and an array, reduce will keep iterating the next element of the array in the function. Also, the funcion returns a value, which is being passed each time.

So, sum is the output of the function until that moment, value is the array element of that iteration